# Haskell "Non type-variable argument in the constraint"

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-errors, pointfree, partial-application

I've created a list of partially applied functions in my REPL like so:

```
listOfPartiallyAppliedFunctions = map (*) [1..100]
```

I would then like to create the list of results from completing the function application, which I can easily do by providing a lambda to the map function like so:

```
let results = map (\x -> x 4) listOfPartiallyAppliedFunctions
```

Which basically means map the function x applied to 4 over the list of partially applied functions, where x is each partially applied function from the list.

However, I thought it would then follow that I could write:

```
let results = map (4) listOfPartiallyAppliedFunctions
```

As there shouldn't be a need to provide a lambda to the map function as it should know to apply 4 to the partially applied functions contained in the `listOfPartiallyAppliedFunctions`.

However, I am getting this error:

```
• Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num ((a -> a) -> b)
  (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
• When checking the inferred type
    it :: forall a b. (Num a, Num ((a -> a) -> b), Enum a) => [b]
```

Can someone help me parse this error? I thought `4` was an instance of type constructor Num?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> However, I thought it would then follow that I could write:
>
> ```
> let results = map (4) listOfPartiallyAppliedFunctions
> ```

No, if you would have performed `\x -> 4 x`, you could replace it with `4`. But since `4` means it is a `Num` instance, and you likely did not make a function `a -> b` an instance of `Num`,  the compiler can not solve this. The compiler thus says that it does not find a way to convert the number `4` into a function, and definitely not a function that takes as input a function `Num a => a -> a`, and then converts this to a `b`.

You can however write the above as just:

```
let results = map ($ 4) listOfPartiallyAppliedFunctions
```

Here we thus perform a [sectioning of an infix operator [Haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator) on the [**`($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36-) function.

Comment: Fantastic answer as always Willem - appreciate it!

Comment: Ah, this is the infix function application operator? I have seen it all over the place but never understood it, so this is like saying "Apply the function (that is the current element in my list of partially applied functions that I'm mapping over) to the value 4?

Comment: @ThomasCook: the infix operator sectioning, specifies that `($ 4)` is equivalent to `\x -> ($) x 4`, since `($)` is implemented as `($) f x = f x`, it is thus equivalent to `\x -> x 4`

Answer (score 8):

[Three "laws" of operator sections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13147064/849891) are

```
(a `op` b)  =  (a `op`) b  =  (`op` b) a  =  op a b
```

(the missing argument goes into the free slot near the operator),

or with `$`,

```
a b  =  (a $ b)  =  (a $) b  =  ($ b) a  =  ($) a b
```

Thus

```
(\ x -> x 4) = (\ x -> x $ 4) = (\ x -> ($ 4) x)
```

and that, by eta-reduction, is

```
($ 4)
```